# How to find breach in concurrency for agent at an instance?

Tags: python

A BPO sector has multiple agents. Each is predefined to handle a number of chats at a particular duration which is known as concurrency. After I generate a report against an agent's email ID I get when chats got assigned to the agent and by when the chat was closed by that agent. Every chat has a unique numerical chat ID.

I tried to write Python code taking the report as a Pandas dataframe (having columns `chat ID`, `agentEmailId`, `AgentAssignmentTimestamp` and `chatClosedTime`). As per user input I enter the concurrency for that agent and check if it is maintained by our system or if any agent has received more than a set concurrency of chats. If more chats got assigned then return the chat ID's in a particular group which got assigned together in a particular instance to the agent.

Variables:

- `df`
  Dataframe containing columns `RoomCode`, `AgentEmail`, `AgentAssignmentTimestamp` and `ChatEndTime`.
- `skill/concurrency`
  User input as set for each unique user.
- `RoomCode`
  Unique number for every chat agent handled.
- `AgentEmail`
  Email id of the agent.
- `AgentAssignmentTimestamp`
  Time when chat got assigned to agent.

My code:

```
def concurrency_checker(df, skill):
    df['RoomCode'] = pd.to_datetime(df['RoomCode'])
    grouped_df = df.groupby(['RoomCode', pd.Grouper(key='AgentEmail', freq='1min')])['AgentAssignmentTimestamp'].min()
    grouped_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    grouped_df.rename(columns={'AgentAssignmentTimestamp': 'assigned_at'}, inplace=True)

    # Create a list of chat IDs for each group.
    group_chat_ids = grouped_df.groupby('group_id')['RoomUrl'].apply(list)

    # Check if the concurrency is maintained for each group.
    for group_id, chat_ids in group_chat_ids.items():
        if len(chat_ids) > skill:
            return chat_ids

    return None
```

Other logic which failed:

```
def check_concurrency(df, concurrency_limit):

    chat_groups = []
    current_group = []
    current_concurrency = 0
    prev_time = None

    for _, row in agent_data.iterrows():
        if prev_time is None:
            prev_time = row['AgentAssignmentTimestamp']

        if row['AgentAssignmentTimestamp'] <= prev_time:
            current_concurrency += 1
            current_group.append(row['chat ID'])
        else:
            if current_concurrency > concurrency_limit:
                chat_groups.append(current_group)

            current_group = [row['chat ID']]
            current_concurrency = 1
            prev_time = row['AgentAssignmentTimestamp']

    if current_concurrency > concurrency_limit:
        chat_groups.append(current_group)

    return chat_groups

# Sample data
data = {
    'chat ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    'agentEmailId': ['agent1', 'agent1', 'agent1', 'agent2', 'agent2', 'agent1', 'agent1', 'agent1'],
    'AgentAssignmentTimestamp': ['2023-08-17 09:00:00', '2023-08-17 09:01:00', '2023-08-17 09:02:00', '2023-08-17 09:01:30', '2023-08-17 09:02:30', '2023-08-17 09:03:00', '2023-08-17 09:04:00', '2023-08-17 09:05:00'],
    'chatClosedTime': ['2023-08-17 09:10:00', '2023-08-17 09:12:00', '2023-08-17 09:15:00', '2023-08-17 09:10:30', '2023-08-17 09:13:00', '2023-08-17 09:08:00', '2023-08-17 09:12:30', '2023-08-17 09:14:00']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
agent_email = 'agent1'
concurrency_limit = 2

chat_groups = check_concurrency(df, agent_email, concurrency_limit)
print("Chat groups with concurrency limit exceeded:")
for group in chat_groups:
    print(group)
```

I'm not getting any output. A dataframe is passed to the below function containing columns `RoomCode`, `AgentEmail`, `AgentAssignmentTimestamp`, `ChatEndTime`. Taking user input skill = 3.

Output:

```
Breached Ids

Group 1 -

Chat id: 6382315
Chat assigned time: 16-06-2023 08:44:16 AM
Chat end time: 16-06-2023 09:10:13 AM

Chat id: 6382309
Chat assigned time: 16-06-2023 08:45:04 AM
Chat end time: 16-06-2023 08:57:35 AM

Chat id: 6382775
Chat assigned time: 16-06-2023 08:51:19 AM
Chat end time: 16-06-2023 09:04:01 AM

Chat id: 6382968
Chat assigned time: 16-06-2023 08:53:19 AM
Chat end time: 16-06-2023 09:03:32 AM
```

Agent can only handle 3 concurrent chats; but as per the output there is a breach in this particular instance and the dataframe contains report for 24 hours. There can be multiple instances or groups where this breach could happen. How to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm unclear on what the problem actually is. There seem to be two steps - _scheduling_, and _schedule analysis_. If the schedule analysis shows that the scheduler screwed up, why are you not showing the code for the scheduler?

Comment: @Reinderien the problem here is the concurrency set for each agent should receive a consistent amount of chats at any instance but as per our organisation after generating the agent report we spotted this anomaly in the scheduler, The scheduler is a backend code that our tech team has access to it and not us.

For our team to get the confirmation we will take this report and run through this concurrency test logic to find the anomaly is sorted out or still exists.

Comment: Again... what's the problem? Is the test report correct?

Comment: the report is correct, only from this report we spotted this anomaly occurring with the concurrency.

Comment: @Reinderien do you need any further clarification, will be glad to answer all your questions.

Comment: You have a report. The report is correct. You've shown the source code only for the report. The scheduler is incorrect. You haven't shown the source code for the scheduler. What do you expect to be contained in an answer?

Comment: so the scheduler code is not visible to us and its with the backend team, what the actual problem is here I am taking in the report as explained in the problem statement and trying to define a function which can read the report and spot the anomaly which had occurred due to the scheduler code and spot the concurrency the chats had breached. The report is perfectly fine its just that after ingesting the report we have to spot the flaw in the concurrency at a particular imstance.

Comment: hello @Reinderien can you please help me here